# YII2 moonlandsoft\phpexcel\Excel::import file does not exist error

Tags: php, excel, import, yii2, widget

I have a requirement to fetch data from an excel file through a widget (i.e) `moonlandsoft/phpexcel/Excel` in `YII2`. For testing, I am trying to place the file in the appropriate view directory (Where I have the below coding in the view file) and test the code. But an error saying

> file doesn't exist
>   [image]

is occurring. Its because I don't know the exact location where the widget trying to fetch data. Where should I place the excel file ( `test.ods` ) to test?

```
<?php
use moonland\phpexcel\Excel;
$filename = "test.ods";
$data = Excel::import(
    $filename, [
        'setFirstRecordAsKeys' => true
    ]
);
print_r($data);
exit;
```

Comment: added an answer see if it works for you.

Comment: Omer as you said as your opinion on not using the extension was right.  It was not working as intended.  Showing error like missing classes may be its because its unstable.  Can you give me link to get a detail view on your recommended extension. May be I could use that. Thank you.!

Comment: @javier i have added a link in the answer already, with the name `arieslee/yii2-phpspreadsheet` you can click on it to go to its GitHub page, also do mark the answer as correct if it helped you. so that others having the same problem might also benefit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the file inside the `web` directory and not in the `views` directory as `web` folder is the place which is publically accessible and includes the entry script `index.php`.

So place your file in the web directory if you are using

- **yii2-app-basic** `YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/web`
- **yii2-advance-app** `YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/frontend/web` or `YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/backend/web`

and your script will start working and you can see the array printed.

Apart from getting it working, my opinion is you should not use this extension because

- It is using the `PHPExcel` which is deprecated and replaced by `PHPSpreadsheet` you can see the message on the console when you install this extension for the first time

  > Package `phpoffice/phpexcel` is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
  >   Use `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` instead.
- `PhpSpreadsheet` is the next version of `PHPExcel`. It breaks compatibility to dramatically improve the code base quality (namespaces, PSR compliance, use of latest PHP language features, etc.).
- Because all efforts have shifted to `PhpSpreadsheet`, `PHPExcel` will no longer be maintained. All contributions for `PHPExcel`, patches and new features, should target `PhpSpreadsheet` develop branch.
- And above all the extension is abandoned and no more maintained since 2016 there are several pull request that was never merged including the update to PHPSpreadsheet but nothing.

A better alternative could be [arieslee/yii2-phpspreadsheet](https://github.com/moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel/pull/27) which is a modified version of the same extension you are using and upgraded to `PHPSpreadsheet`, you won't need to change anything in the code its the same extension with same methods.